# SQL - Return all rows before certain date for each partition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have two tables like so:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2022 |
| 2 | 01-02-2022 |
| 3 | 01-10-2022 |
| 4 | 01-03-2022 |

| ID | Date | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-05-2022 | forward |
| 1 | 12-20-2021 | stop |
| 1 | 10-15-2021 | stop |
| 1 | 01-20-2022 | forward |
| 2 | 12-30-2021 | stop |
| 2 | 12-14-2021 | forward |
| 2 | 12-16-2021 | forward |
| 2 | 12-01-2021 | reverse |
| 2 | 01-15-2022 | forward |
| 3 | 01-01-2022 | reverse |
| 3 | 01-02-2022 | reverse |
| 3 | 01-03-2022 | stop |
| 4 | 10-15-2021 | reverse |
| 4 | 03-04-2021 | forward |
| 4 | 01-10-2021 | reverse |

I am looking to return a table that consists of each ID and a count of how many actions took place before the corresponding date in the first table. So for example, ID 1 would return a count of 2 because 2 of its actions took place before 01-01-2022.

I would expect the final table to look something like:

| ID | Count_action |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If there are no matching actions, do you want count_action of zero, or no row?

Comment: count_action of 0 would be fine

Answer (score 0):

A left join and aggregate count function should do.  Notice we join on the dates being <= date from.  Left join preserves all Id's from A so we will get a 0 count on such records when no dates in the B table are prior to the date in A for the related ID.

```
SELECT A.ID, coalesce(count(B.*),0) Count_action
FROM A  --A is your first table with 1 date per ID.
LEFT JOIN B
  on A.ID= B.ID
  and B.Date <=A.Date
GROUP BY A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

A left join will do it:

```
select p.id, count(a.id) as Count_action
from parentTable p
left join actionTable a on a.id = p.id
  and a.date < p.date
group by p.id
```

Because `count()` ignores nulls, `count(a.id)` is used to get a count of 0 for id’s that have no actions before their date, instead of the usual `count(*)` which would give a count one 1 in that case.

Importantly, the condition `a.date < p.date` is in the *join*. If it were in the *where*, the left join would be effectively changed to an *inner* join, and id’s without matching actions would then not appear at all in the result.